# Work done on springs

Tags: work, spring

The derivation of work done on a spring is known. We find work done on a mass $m$ connected to a spring and we say that's the work done to stretch the spring. We get : $$W=\frac{kx²}{2}$$ (Now let's assume the spring has some mass)but if we calculate work done to stretch the spring by formula, then the work done on a body is defined as force times displacement of body's COM (assuming force is along displacement).We then get that work done in stretching is : $$W=\frac{kx²}{4}.$$ Derivation of this above formula is as follows.
Let  the spring be pulled by force  through a distance $dx$ then $COM$ displaces by $\frac{dx}{2}$  then $$dW=\frac{kx}{2}dx$$ integrating this result yields : $$W=\frac{kx²}{4}.$$

Please help me find out mistake, particularly why this contradiction arises.

Comment: " the work done on a body is defined as force times displacement of body's COM" That's not true. A spring is not a rigid body, so some of the mass is moving a farther or lesser distance than the COM of the spring AND the force is not constant. Consider the spring to be a set of coils, each with mass M/L dx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the mass by itself (infinitely slowly, and without gravity field) doesn't do any work. With gravity field, and moving in direction of the gravity vector, moving the mass is still not related to the spring constant .. 
So having a vertical spring, in a gravity field:

dw_mass   = m* g*0.5*dx

dw_strain = k* x*dx

sum: dW =  w_mass + w_strain = m*g*0.5 dx + k*x* dx

integration x=0 .. x=s:    W=m*g*0.5s+0.5*k*s^2

Answer (score 1):

When analysing massive springs, we convert the problem into one where the spring is ideal and massless with the same spring constant but has a mass attached at its end, using the [effective mass of the spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(spring%E2%80%93mass_system))